# jquery mobile listview arrow not showing left

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am building an app (or taking a shot at it) but need the list view to be RTL (Right to Left) where the arrow shows in the left side instead of the right and the text must be aligned right to left. I have the following but not working:

```
<div data-role="content">
        <p >اختر التصنيف:</p>
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li ><a href="acura.html">الكمبيوترات</a></li>
            <li><a href="cccc.html">الجوالات</a></li>
            <li><a href="cccc.html">ملابس</a></li>
            <li><a href="cccc.html">مطاعم</a></li>
            <li><a href="cccc.html">فنادق</a></li>
            <li><a href="cccc.html">خدمات</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->
```

I do not wish to use buttons as indicated here http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/buttons/buttons-icons.html because they just don't look good as the list view. Can this be done?

Comment: do you want the bullets at the right side?

Answer (score 0):

I found that someone managed to re-write the jquery file and modify it to RTL. Excellent and works well

http://www.intlaqa.com/jquery-mobile-rtl/